# Build url with 'sec:authentication="name"'

Tags: spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

I would like to know if there is a possibility to build the url.

What i use:

- spring boot + spring security
- Thymeleaf

with the following expression, i get the username

```
sec:authentication="name"
```

If i do the following, the current username would be display

```
<span id="userName" sec:authentication="name">Testuser</span>
```

but now i would like to build a url like the following:

```
<a th:href="@{'~/' + __${{sec.authentication='name'}}__ + '/edit'}" class="text-left">Settings</a>
```

with this i get the following error:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1009E:(pos 4): Property or field 'authentication' cannot be set on null
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it's described in the docs here: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3

Your url should be:

`<a th:href="@{|~/${#authentication.name}/edit|}" class="text-left">Settings</a>`